# Android (ReactNative) release build showing white screen after splash

Tags: android, react-native

After taking release build, android showing white screen after splash screen. No issues while run in debug. And no issue in iOS. Only the issue is in Android after taking the Release build.

Comment: the app must be crashing. but may not see a red screen since its release mode. And sometimes it will not be a fatal error so that app will not crash but will show a white screen

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: Do you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: any idea to how to resolve the issue ?